# create dummy by group for first/largest change of value in a column pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to create a dummy variable by 'ID' that takes the value of one starting from either the largest or the first change in the column 'Value' (whenever there are two or more changes). However, if the largest change happens in 2009 or after, then the dummy will start from the first change instead of the largest (e.g., ID = 3), if any. The output should look like this:

```
d = {'ID': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4],
     'Year': [2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010],
     'Value': [0, 6.25, 31.25, 0, 0, 0, 6.25, 5, 0, 5, 0, 0, 3, 6, 3, 0, 0, 25, 0, 0],
     'Dummy' : [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data = d)
df
```

Comment: to clarify, if the year is before 2009 you want the dummy variable to increment based on the largest step change?

Comment: and  2. you are only considering positive changes (ie current year>prior year)?

Comment: yes, if the year is before 2009, I want the dummy based on the largest step change, and 2. I'm considering both positive and negative changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your ID 3 example is irrelevant as the largest change happens in 2008 as value increases from 0-3 in that year. You see the same change again in 2009 when it goes from 2008 to 2009. So you need to included the logic on what you want to do with a tie (where tie for largest change for a given ID occurs both after and prior to 2009). So you might want to change this based on that feedback.

```
# get the change
df['delta'] = (df['Value'] - df.groupby(['ID'])['Value'].shift(1)).fillna(0)
# get the max change
df['max_delta'] = df.groupby(['ID'])['delta'].transform('max')
# check if max_delta occurred in year prior to 2009
df['conditional'] = np.where(
   ( df['delta']==df['max_delta']) & (df['Year'] < 2009),
   True,
   False
)
# anywhere the max value occurred before 2009 we want to start the increment
df.loc[df['conditional']==True,'dummy_calc'] = 1
# foward fill
df['dummy_calc'] = df.groupby(['ID'])['dummy_calc'].ffill()
df['dummy_calc'] = df['dummy_calc'].fillna(0)
# check vs yours
df['check_col'] = df['Dummy'] == df['dummy_calc']
df
```

Output:

```
ID  Year    Value   Dummy   delta   max_delta   conditional dummy_calc  check_col
0   1   2006    0.00    0   0.00    25.00         False       0.0         True
1   1   2007    6.25    0   6.25    25.00         False       0.0         True
2   1   2008    31.25   1   25.00   25.00         True        1.0         True
3   1   2009    0.00    1   -31.25  25.00         False       1.0         True
4   1   2010    0.00    1   0.00    25.00         False       1.0         True
5   2   2006    0.00    0   0.00    6.25          False       0.0         True
6   2   2007    6.25    1   6.25    6.25          True        1.0         True
7   2   2008    5.00    1   -1.25   6.25          False       1.0         True
8   2   2009    0.00    1   -5.00   6.25          False       1.0         True
9   2   2010    5.00    1   5.00    6.25          False       1.0         True
10  3   2006    0.00    0   0.00    3.00          False       0.0         True
11  3   2007    0.00    0   0.00    3.00          False       0.0         True
12  3   2008    3.00    1   3.00    3.00          True        1.0         True
13  3   2009    6.00    1   3.00    3.00          False       1.0         True
14  3   2010    3.00    1   -3.00   3.00          False       1.0         True
15  4   2006    0.00    0   0.00    25.00         False       0.0         True
16  4   2007    0.00    0   0.00    25.00         False       0.0         True
17  4   2008    25.00   1   25.00   25.00         True        1.0         True
18  4   2009    0.00    1   -25.00  25.00         False       1.0         True
19  4   2010    0.00    1   0.00    25.00         False       1.0         True
```

Comment: Many thanks for your post, I agree with your comments and suggestion, this is indeed what I am looking for in a bit more complex dataset, so I added some modifications. One last question: how could I modify the code to consider only positive changes? given that in for some IDs I can have a negative change of 'Value', then a zero and then a positive change smaller than the negative one in absolute value (In this case delta will be positive for the first large negative change to zero and positive but lower for the second positive change)